# Datepicker not working on Visualforce Page When standardStylesheets="false"

Tags: visualforce, inputfield, date-picker

I want to disable standard stylesheets for a Visualforce page, but when I disable it, `apex:inputfield` does not provide date picker for date fields.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Opportunity" standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

When `standardStylesheets` are enabled it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `standardStyleSheets="true"`, SFDC generates HTML markup that includes

```
<div class="datePicker" id="datePicker" style="display: none; left: 230px; top: 42px;"><div class="dateBar"><img src="/img/s.gif" alt="Previous Month" class="calLeft" onblur="this.className = 'calLeft';" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.prevMonth();" onfocus="this.className = 'calLeftOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'calLeft';" onmouseover="this.className = 'calLeftOn';" title="Previous Month"><select id="calMonthPicker" name="calMonthPicker" title="Month"><option value="0">January</option>
<option value="1">February</option>
<option value="2">March</option>
<option value="3">April</option>
<option value="4">May</option>
<option value="5">June</option>
<option value="6">July</option>
<option value="7">August</option>
<option value="8">September</option>
<option value="9">October</option>
<option value="10">November</option>
<option value="11">December</option>
</select><img src="/img/s.gif" alt="Next Month" class="calRight" onblur="this.className = 'calRight';" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.nextMonth();" onfocus="this.className = 'calRightOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'calRight';" onmouseover="this.className = 'calRightOn';" title="Next Month"><select id="calYearPicker" name="calYearPicker" title="Year"><option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2023">2023</option>
<option value="2024">2024</option>
</select></div><div class="calBody"><table class="calDays" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="datePickerCalendar"><tbody><tr><th class="dayOfWeek" scope="col">Sun</th><th class="dayOfWeek" scope="col">Mon</th><th class="dayOfWeek" scope="col">Tue</th><th class="dayOfWeek" scope="col">Wed</th><th class="dayOfWeek" scope="col">Thu</th><th class="dayOfWeek" scope="col">Fri</th><th class="dayOfWeek" scope="col">Sat</th></tr>
<tr class="calRow" id="calRow1"><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekend prevMonth">30</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">1</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">2</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">3</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">4</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">5</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekend">6</td></tr>
<tr class="calRow" id="calRow2"><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekend">7</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">8</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">9</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">10</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">11</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">12</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekend">13</td></tr>
<tr class="calRow" id="calRow3"><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekend">14</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">15</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">16</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday todayDate">17</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">18</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">19</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekend">20</td></tr>
<tr class="calRow" id="calRow4"><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekend">21</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">22</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">23</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">24</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">25</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">26</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekend">27</td></tr>
<tr class="calRow" id="calRow5"><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekend">28</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">29</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">30</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday">31</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday nextMonth">1</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekday nextMonth">2</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);" class="weekend nextMonth">3</td></tr>
<tr class="calRow" id="calRow6" style="display: none;"><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);">&nbsp;</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);">&nbsp;</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);">&nbsp;</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);">&nbsp;</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);">&nbsp;</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);">&nbsp;</td><td onblur="hiOff(this);" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate(this);" onfocus="hiOn(this);" onmouseout="hiOff(this);" onmouseover="hiOn(this);">&nbsp;</td></tr>
</tbody></table><div class="buttonBar"><a href="javascript:%20void%280%29%3B" class="calToday" onclick="DatePicker.datePicker.selectDate('today');return false;">Today</a></div></div></div>
```

with `standardStyleSheets="false"`, the `div` is not generated at all

The [VF documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_custom.htm?search_text=standardstylesheets) states:

> If you don’t load the Salesforce style sheets, components that require them don’t display correctly.

So, you'll need to use your own datePicker from some Javascript library.  The book *VisualForce Development Cookbook 2nd edition* by the esteemed Keir Bowden aka Bob Buzzard, chapter 3 "Adding a custom datepicker" shows how to do this. This is a great book for VF developers who aren't using Aura or LWC.

The purpose of `standardStyleSheets="false"` is for applications that want total control over the look-and-feel (CSS) of the page.